# I want to fetch only single row data from the table with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
8_BeginString 9_BodyLength 34_MsgSeqNum 35_MsgType
------------- ------------ ------------ ----------
FIX.4.4       NULL         NULL         NULL      
NULL          486          NULL         NULL      
NULL          NULL         NULL         AE        
NULL          NULL         157          NULL      
NULL          NULL         NULL         NULL      
NULL          NULL         NULL         NULL      
NULL          NULL         NULL         NULL      
NULL          NULL         NULL         NULL      
NULL          NULL         NULL         NULL      
NULL          NULL         NULL         NULL
```

I want this output:

```
8_BeginString 9_BodyLength 34_MsgSeqNum 35_MsgType
------------- ------------ ------------ ----------
FIX.4.4       486           157         AE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select max(col1), max(col2), max(col3), max(col4)
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select all_column_names from table
group by all_column_name.
```

if there is only 1 record in each column then

```
select max(col1), max(col2) ... from table
```

Comment: Thank you Sas  :)